# How to add Chronometer inside service?

Tags: android, service, counter, chronometer

I am triying to add Chronometer inside service  and fetch value.But i am not getting correct Chronometer value.

```
public class NewLocationUpdateService extends Service  {
    Chronometer chronometer;
     private static final int LOC_API_CALL_INTERVAL = 60 * 1000;

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {


        chronometer = new Chronometer(NewLocationUpdateService.this);
                chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                chronometer.start();

        startTimer();

        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {


        return binder;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {

        return super.onUnbind(intent);

    }
  @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();


        stopTimer();

    }

//Timer related functions

    private void startTimer(){
        if(timer!=null ){
            return;
        }
        timer=new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                long millis=SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - chronometer.getBase();
                long seconds = (millis / 1000) % 60;
                Log.e("timefortest", "" + seconds);
             }
        }, LOC_API_CALL_INTERVAL, LOC_API_CALL_INTERVAL);
    }

    private void stopTimer(){

        if(null!=timer){
            timer.cancel();
            timer=null;
        }
    }


}
```

The output i am getting

```
 E/timefortest: 7
 E/timefortest: 1
 E/timefortest: 0
 E/timefortest: 5
 E/timefortest: 0
 E/timefortest: 0
 E/timefortest: 0
 E/timefortest: 0
 E/timefortest: 1
 E/timefortest: 0
 E/timefortest: 2
```

i am expecting

```
 E/timefortest: 60
 E/timefortest: 120
 E/timefortest: 180
 E/timefortest: 240
```

let me know what i did wrong.my purpose is i need to start counter inside service and i need to fetch  the value.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should remove the mod 60.here is an example.

```
 long timeWhenStopped =  SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - chronometer.getBase();
    int seconds = (int) timeWhenStopped / 1000;
```